# argsort get order of each element

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array and I want to get the order of each element.

```
a=[1.83976,1.57624,1.00528,1.55184]
np.argsort(a)
```

the above code return

```
array([2, 3, 1, 0], dtype=int64)
```

but I want to get the array of the order of each element.
e.g.

```
[0, 1, 3, 2]

means a[0] is largest number (0th)
a[1] is 1th
a[2] is 3rd
a[3] is 2nd
```

Answer (score 1):

Ill explain,`np.argsort(np.argsort(a))` gives the element in there order like `1.83976` is the highest value in the array so it is assigned the highest value `3`. I just subtracted the value from `len(a)-1` to get your output.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=[1.83976,1.57624,1.00528,1.55184]
>>> np.argsort(a)
array([2, 3, 1, 0])
>>> np.argsort(np.argsort(a))
array([3, 2, 0, 1])
>>> [len(a)-i for i in np.argsort(np.argsort(a))]
[1, 2, 4, 3]
>>> [len(a)-1-i for i in np.argsort(np.argsort(a))]
[0, 1, 3, 2]
>>> np.array([len(a)-1]*len(a))-np.argsort(np.argsort(a))
array([0, 1, 3, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

By default argsort returnes indexes of sorted elements in ascending order. As you need descending order, argsort(-a) will give you right sorted indexes. To get the rank of elements you need to apply argsort again.

```
a = np.array([1.83976,1.57624,1.00528,1.55184])
indx_sorted = np.argsort(-a)
np.argsort(indx_sorted)
>>> array([0, 1, 3, 2])
```

Comment: Hi! While this may provide an answer, it is generally discouraged on StackOverflow to leave code only answers. Please explain *why* this is a solution as it will help OP and future visitors. Thanks!